# Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:1.0-beta-6

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I am trying to build the project `jbpm-designer` which I cloned from the following repository

https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-designer.git

While building this project it throws the following errors. How to resolve this issue?

Stack trace:

```
 The project org.jbpm:jbpm-designer:7.16.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\mohammed.javad\Desktop\jbpm-designer-master\pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:1.0-beta-6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:pom:1.0-beta-6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:1.0-beta-6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6 ()
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:211)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.resolveExtensionArtifacts(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:377)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.createProjectRealm(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:237)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultModelBuildingListener.buildExtensionsAssembled(DefaultModelBuildingListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingEventCatapult$1.fire(ModelBuildingEventCatapult.java:43)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.fireEvent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1041)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:391)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:374)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:536)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:632)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:581)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:233)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6 ()
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:202)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:199)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:jar:1.0-beta-6
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:172)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:196)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:pom:1.0-beta-6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:197)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:pom:1.0-beta-6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:949)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:695)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:689)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:445)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:608)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
        ... 8 more
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.wildfly.swarm:bom:pom:2018.3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version @ org.kie:kie-parent:7.16.0-SNAPSHOT, D:\repo\org\kie\kie-parent\7.16.0-SNAPSHOT\kie-parent-7.16.0-SNAPSHOT.pom, line 2506, column 19 -> [Help 3]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.wildfly.swarm:bom:pom:2018.3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:942)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:403)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:374)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:536)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:632)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:581)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:233)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.wildfly.swarm:bom:pom:2018.3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:197)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:323)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:155)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.wildfly.swarm:bom:pom:2018.3.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:949)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:695)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:689)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:445)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:608)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
        ... 8 more
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.arquillian.selenium:selenium-bom:pom:3.13.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version @ org.jboss.integration-platform:jboss-integration-platform-bom:8.3.2.Final, D:\repo\org\jboss\integration-platform\jboss-integration-platform-bom\8.3.2.Final\jboss-integration-platform-bom-8.3.2.Final.pom, line 2057, column 19 -> [Help 3]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.arquillian.selenium:selenium-bom:pom:3.13.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.importDependencyManagement(DefaultModelBuilder.java:942)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:403)
        at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:374)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:536)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:632)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:581)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:233)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.arquillian.selenium:selenium-bom:pom:3.13.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:541)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:220)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:197)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:323)
        at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:155)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.arquillian.selenium:selenium-bom:pom:3.13.0 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:949)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:940)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:695)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:689)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector.get(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:445)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:460)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Error transferring file: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:143)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:608)
        at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1301)
        at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.LightweightHttpWagon.fillInputData(LightweightHttpWagon.java:115)
        ... 8 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
[ERROR] [Help 3] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you cannot reach MavenCentral. This is often an issue with the firewall or proxy that your company (or you) are using.

Comment: So no solution for this issue?

Comment: The solution is to reconfigure the firewall or proxy. If you are inside a company, you probably need to speak to the administrators of the network. Alternatively, they could set up a Nexus/Artifactory that is outside the firewall to proxy MavenCentral, and give you access to that Nexus/Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to stumble here with this same problem, one solution is to add .m2/settings.xml in your home directory with the proxy configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>http</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>myproxy.com</host>
            <port>8010</port>
            <nonProxyHosts>myStuff.com|localhost</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
        <proxy>
            <id>https</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <host>myproxy.com</host>
            <port>8010</port>
            <nonProxyHosts>myStuff.com|localhost</nonProxyHosts>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
```

(xml and settings tags for reference if you don't already have settings.xml)